# Android || button configuration || return intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to configure a Helper Java class that will handle any button click and return intent.

as I need to configure a separate class that will handle the clicks

```
public class MainSreeen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_sreeen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // instantiate the button
    Button Google_map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    ExternalOnClickListener Google= new ExternalOnClickListener();
    startActivity(Google.ExternalOnClickListener());
```

the ExternalOnClickListener class

```
    import android.content.Intent;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import java.util.Locale;

    public class ExternalOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public Intent intent;

    public Intent ExternalOnClickListener(Button button) {
        return intent;
        // keep references for your onClick logic
    }

    public Intent ExternalOnClickListener() {
        return intent;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Double latitude= 59.915494;
        Double longitude = 30.409456;
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

    }

}
```

I am not able to return the Intent

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible that way. When you would like to start new `Activity` after button click, follow this approach:

1. Inside your `onClick(View v)` method obtain a `context` from a view and start `Activity` using this `context`

   ```
   ((Activity)v.getContext).startActivity(intent).
   ```
2. Set on click listener on a button. You can do that inside your `ExternalOnClickListener` contructor. **Remember, that constructor does not return anything.**

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(this).
   ```